# Electrostatics and motion

Tags: electrostatics

When two protons move antiparallel they attract or repel.I know when they move parallel they repel so in antiparallel tey will attract? But some books say that electrostatics is  independent of relative motion. Basically i am comparing current in two wires with two protons... As we know two wires when they carry current and if currents are parallel wires will attract and vice versa. If we take simply two protons what will happens it will behave like two wires or there behaviour will be different??

Comment: Protons always repel each other. What do you mean by antiparallel?

Comment: Charged particles in motion does not belong to the purview of electrostatics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two forces at work. The electrostatic force, $F \propto \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2} \hat r$, is indeed independent of the motion of charges (modulo relativistic effects, I think). This force is always repulsive between two like charges, since then $q_1 = q_2$ and the product is positive.

The other force at work is the generation of a magnetic field via the "current" created by a charged particle in motion. For two electrons in motion with non-relativistic velocities, this force is dramatically smaller than the electrostatic force, so the overall result is that the electrons repel.

The effects of current that cause two wires with antiparallel currents to attract are mainly visible because those wires are electrically neutral: there are as many protons as electrons, so the overall electrostatic force is nil. If you just had two antiparallel streams of electrons, with no protons present, they would repel (strongly).